# Generating SQL by data modification on Swing table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to build  a jdbc client tool. it will display data that returned by select query in Swing table, and may allow user to edit the data on the table. my question is what's the best way to generate standard sql string(**insert delete update**) for saving modification back  to database ?

1. is there any open library can help me ?
2. I need to support common database such as mysql, oracle, db2, sysbase, informix.
3. I need to support arbitary sql query, no ORM framework used.
4. if you think I should do it by meself, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: ... why?  There's probably several out there already.

Comment: @Clockwork sorry for replaying late, because good jdbc client tool such as dbvisualzier is not free, free tools  such as eclipse's datatools is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use [Apache Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org)

2) It supports common databases  (such as mysql, oracle, db2, sysbase, informix)

http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/database-support.html

3) You can use arbitary SQL queries by using **SQLTemplate** class. It allows to customizing SQL dialects.

http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/sqltemplate-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into Hibernate (Java)

or

Java DB OBjects

http://dbobjects.sourceforge.net/